# Android Broadcast Receiver not working within service when app is closed

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, background-process, wifimanager

I am using service to manage wifi network state. It works almost fine as long as app is running. But when app is closed, broadcast receiver within service don't work.

```
public class WifiService extends Service {

private class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    String wifiNameN;
    int wifiIdN;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            NetworkInfo netInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            assert netInfo != null;
            Log.i("SerSC","=State"+wifiName);
            Log.i("SerSC","=State"+wifiId);

            if(netInfo.getDetailedState().equals(NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED)) {

                Log.i("SerSC","=Connection");

            } else if(netInfo.getDetailedState().equals(NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTING)) {

            } else if(netInfo.getDetailedState().equals(NetworkInfo.DetailedState.DISCONNECTING)) {

                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                assert wifiManager != null;
                WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                wifiInfo.getSSID();
                wifiNameN = netInfo.getExtraInfo();
                Log.i("SerSC","=D"+wifiNameN+"---"+wifiIdN);
                wifiIdN = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

            } else if(netInfo.getDetailedState().equals(NetworkInfo.DetailedState.DISCONNECTED)) {

                if (wifiName.equals(wifiNameN) && wifiId == wifiIdN) {
                    Log.i("SerSC","=DC"+wifiNameN+"---"+wifiIdN);
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    // Vibrate for 5000 milliseconds
                    assert v != null;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(1000, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                    } else {
                        //deprecated in API 26
                        v.vibrate(1000);
                    }
                    // I want to show a notification on system window e.g like messenger chat head appears when message comes
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

private String wifiName;
private int wifiId;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(new WifiReceiver(), filter);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("SerSC", "Service Started");
    if (intent != null) {
        wifiName = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.WIFI_NAME_TAG);
        wifiId = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.WIFI_NETWORK_TAG, -1);
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("SerSC","Service Destroyed");
    unregisterReceiver(new WifiReceiver());
}
```

}

Also this condition is working

```
if(netInfo.getDetailedState().equals(NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED)) {

            Log.i("SerSC","=Connection");

        }
```

But NetworkInfo.DetailedState.DISCONNECTING and DISCONNECTED are not working when I turn off WIFI device.
I want to run service permanently in background  and listen to network state even if app is not running. Please don't provide the links. Write the Code if you are determined to help me

Comment: Because android will kill your service when it will enter doze mode, so it would be better to use foreground service for you

Comment: I said  I want to run service in background even when app is not running/open.

Answer (score 0):

just register the broadcast receiver outside the service.